# Criar Tag HTML com Angular 5?

Tags: angularjs

Com angularjs eu criava uma diretiva, e apenas importava utlizando a tag  e ela já estava disponível para utilizar em qualquer arquivo HTML.
Eu utilizava isso para centralizar alguns objetos visuais que se repetiam em várias partes do sistema, como por exemplo, a navbar, sidebar, menus..
Como faço isso utilizando angular 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Angular 2+, o mesmo comportamento pode ser obtido através de componentes.

Você cria um componente, e importa o mesmo dentro de outros componentes.

[image: Estrutura de componentes]

Recomendo a leitura da documentação do Angular,[especificamente a parte sobre arquitetura](https://angular.io/guide/architecture)

Comment: Eu li essa documentação, ao importar e tentar utilizar o component, recebo o seguinte erro: "Template parse errors:
'NavbarComponent' is not a known element:
1. If 'NavbarComponent' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("[ERROR ->]<NavbarComponent></NavbarComponent>
")"

Comment: Seu componente A (Navbar) deve estar dentro de um módulo, que deve ser importado dentro do módulo do componente B (App)

Comment: Eu fiz uma demo no stackblitz para ficar claro: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjnvgd

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e atenção.. Funcionou.. Eu estava errando em colocar o nome da classe como tag, na verdade o nome da tag é o "selector".

Comment: Disponha, caso a resposta tenha resolvido a sua pergunta, marque a resposta como correta logo acima.